# ListViewItem Context Menu Get Data from ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

I'm trying to create a context menu, so that when you right click the `ListViewItem`, the user is presented with a list of options. The problem is; I can't get the refrenced item linked to the `ListViewItem` in the `Click` event.

I think it may be because I'm putting the `ContextMenu` in the wrong place in my XAML. I have been searching and playing around for ages, but think it could have something to do with the `DataTemplate` I'm using where the examples weren't in templates.

```
<ListView Margin="0" Name="FileImagesListView"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">                             
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Mouse.MouseEnter" Handler="MouseEnterPicFileListItem" />
            <EventSetter Event="Mouse.MouseLeave" Handler="MouseLeavePicFileListItem"/>          
        </Style>      
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrushColourID, Converter={StaticResource BorderColourConverter}}" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2">
                <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=TimeAgo}" Margin="0,7" ></TextBlock>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource CircularLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="35" Margin="0,-8,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=MatchedCount}" Visibility="{Binding Path=MatchedCount, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfGreaterThanOne}}" ></Label>
                    </Grid>
                    <Image Name="FilePic" Height="Auto" Width="160" Source="{Binding Path=BitmapPicture}"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="3" Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: How do you try to get the item?

Comment: Can you show us your context menu XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can get the data item by just calling `myListViewItem.DataContext` and casting it into whatever it should be.

```
private void ListViewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;
    if (item == null) return;

    MyDataItem = item.DataContext as MyDataItem;

    // Do whatever here
}
```

As a side note, WPF ContextMenus do not share the same VisualTree as your application, so trying to bind them to your main UI works differently. Its hard to tell if that is related to your problem because I see no `ContextMenu` or `Click` event in your question.

**Edit**
If your ContextMenu is on a ListBoxItem, then you need to refer to your ContextMenu's `PlacementTarget` to get the `ListBoxItem` that the `ContextMenu` is attached to

Comment: Apologies for the ambigiuity, I wasn't 100% sure where the ContextMenu should be placed in the XAML.  If I attempt to add the ContextMenu as                `<ListView.ContextMenu>`  `<ContextMenu>`
                    `<MenuItem Name="Option1MenuItem" Header="Option1" Click="Option1MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>`
                    `<MenuItem Header="Option2" ></MenuItem>`
                `</ContextMenu>`
            `</ListView.ContextMenu>`

Comment: The problem here is that the sender from Option1MenuItem_Click is of type Controls.MenuItem which doesn't have the referenced item displayed in ListViewItem.  I think you are right in that the ContextMenu's binding works differently to what I am used to. Apologies for the formatting and double post, it didn't all fit in one comment.

Comment: @SpeedBird527 You need to refer to your ContextMenu's `PlacementTarget` to get the `ListBoxItem` that the `ContextMenu` is attached to